# Ubuntu 64bit 11.04 server and curl install fail

Tags: curl, 64-bit, ubuntu-11.04

So I wanted to install curl with HTTPS protocol, I did it like so:

1. sudo -i wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.21.6.tar.bz2
2. sudo -i tar jxf curl-7.21.6.tar.bz2
3. sudo -i rm curl-7.21.6.tar.bz2
4. sudo -i cd curl-7.21.6/
5. sudo -i ./configure
6. sudo -i make prefix=/usr/local all
7. sudo -i make prefix=/usr/local install

and last I tried: **sudo -i curl --version** to see if I succeeded and the answer was "No!". The error I got is here:

```
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prefix=/usr/local` should be set in `configure` instead, like:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Not in `make`.  However, `configure` sets prefix to `/usr/local` by default in autotools, so you don't need to specify that anyways. Then just run:

```
make clean && make && sudo make install
```

Note that when compiling code, you should always do it as a standard user, not as sudo or root. Only do it for make install, which is where you actually need permissions to do things like chmod and moving files around. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @onteria_ - I first tried 'make clean && make && sudo make install', but this didn't work, then I deleted the folder from /tmp/ dir and redownloaded it as standard user, unpacked it and tried command ''make && sudo make install'' but I still get the same error :(

Comment: @Marko odd... try `/usr/local/bin/curl --version`

Comment: @Marko hmm.. okay how about `ls /usr/local/lib/libcurl*`?

Comment: @onteria_ - `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.la  /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so` Should I just try then `sudo apt-get install curl`? Bad side is that in respostiory it's older: Version: 7.21.3-1

Comment: @Marko Sure, I was going to suggest that, but I thought you were installing this specific version for building some other library. If you just want it to work with https, go ahead and use the repository version.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4`

Answer (score 3):

Try running `sudo ldconfig` on CentOs 5.0 (after adding a symlink from /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 to /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4). See: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2009-05/0014.html